# Converting from base64 string to varbinary(max) in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pdf, base64, varbinary

I have PDF documents stored in my table as binary, the column that stores the bytes for the PDFs is type `varbinary(max)`. I want to `update` one record with an updated document in SQL Studio, the way I am attempting to accomplish this is like below

```
UPDATE table
SET file_bytes=CONVERT(varbinary(max),'JVBERi0xLjYNCiW2JqDQo8PC9UeX...0YNCg==') --this is a base64 string
WHERE id='73c75254-ad86-466e-a881-969e2c6e7a04';
```

The query runs, but when I try to download the document (via the website), it throws an error message that reads `PDF header signature not found.`

Is this conversion even possible?

Comment: The website should be adding the correct file / mime-type headers, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, the documents I upload via the webservice are downloading fine. This is what the website has 
    `Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & packetName.Replace(".", "_"))
    Response.BinaryWrite(mergedPdfBytes)
    Response.End()`

Comment: I think you need to put that code in the question (not the comment), and also describe what the webservice does different from the database update. Also how did you come up with that `'JVBER...'` string, and should it be `N'JVBER...'`? Also are you sure you want to store PDF files in a VARBINARY(MAX) column? Most have better luck on the file system or using Filestream or FileTable...

Comment: A windows application converts the PDFs to base64 and passes that to the webservice, the service takes the PDF base64 in a byte array and then is just an insert command in a stored procedure. The webservice code looks like this `cmd.Parameters.Add("@file_bytes", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = fileData.Bytes;` .... this application is already in production, so changing the data type is not an option

Comment: So try changing your update to use the `N` prefix on the string - I bet it's Unicode (and you lose that when you don't prefix it correctly).

Comment: Added the `N` prefix and still the same thing

Comment: Ok, sorry, you've exhausted my expertise here. (I learned over a decade ago to not jam files into SQL Server. You will probably learn this lesson too.)

Comment: I might need to create a little web interface to do this :( , and this is what I was hoping to avoid since this is just a one time thing...thanks

Answer (score 19):

It is possible by using the approach described here : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqltips/2008/06/30/converting-from-base64-to-varbinary-and-vice-versa/

It's a two-step process, first you declare a variable :

```
declare @str varchar(max) = '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAAAAAAAD/==';
```

Then you can use the variable in your SQL statement as follow :

```
INSERT INTO Documents (Name, Body, MIMEType)
VALUES('12446_photo.jpg', cast(N'' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@str"))', 'varbinary(max)'), 'image/jpeg');
```

Comment: You don't need the variable.
`cast('/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAAAAAAAD/==' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(.)', 'varbinary(max)')`
Since every character in base64 is considered text in xml, the whole string becomes a single text node.

Answer (score 5):

### Convert a base64 to `varbinary`

```
SELECT
   Id,
   AttachmentBase64, --the base64 value we want converted to varbinary
   CAST(AttachmentBase64 AS xml).value('xs:base64Binary(.)', 'varbinary(max)') AS AttachmentBinary
FROM Attachments
```

### Convert `varbinary` column to base64

```
SELECT
   Id,
   AttachmentBinary, --the varbinary value we want converted to base64
   CAST('' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("AttachmentBinary"))', 'varchar(max)') AS AttachmentBase64
FROM Attachments
```