# Save base64 encoded string image data in Image type column in SQL Server with vbscript

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, adodb

I have a column named IMGDATA of type Image in my  MyImages in SQL Server server
I have a string variable named MyImageStringBase64Encoded that contains a base64 encoded image. I m trying to save this image to the database

```
Set Command1 = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
Command1.ActiveConnection = MyConnection_STRING
Command1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MyImages (IMGNAME,IMGDATA)  VALUES (?,?)"
Command1.Parameters(0) = "My Image Name"
Command1.Parameters(1) = MyImageStringBase64Encoded
Command1.CommandType = 1
Command1.Execute()
```

The code above will save corrupted image data in the db. Maybe I have to save bytes?

possibly related but not sure how to apply them

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24925145/934967

[MS Access: Sending image as varbinary to stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49077536/934967)

I 'm new to vbscript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting from base64 string to varbinary(max) in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897140/converting-from-base64-string-to-varbinarymax-in-sql-server)

Comment: You need to convert the base64 encoded string into it’s binary representation before saving it to SQL Server.

Comment: Just noticed you mention [tag:mysql] in the question but the question is tagged [tag:sql-server], which is it?

Comment: The `image` data type has been deprecated since SQL Server 2005, you should use the `varbinary(max)` column type instead. You also shouldn't need to base64 encode it, just supply a byte array to the [CreateParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/createparameter-method-ado) method with the Type set to `adBinary`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning still depends on if they are using [tag:sql-server] or not but would suggest `adVarBinary` over `adBinary`.

Comment: @Lankymart thank you for your comments. Also I edited the typo. It is SQL Server